# Neo4j - bus transportation-modeling-how to store location, time and Geo-code of all buses at their corresponding stop on different routes

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to implement the graph databases - neo4j - for my Transportation system.

The goals are

- to analyze the existing relational data, optimize the routes, understand the performance of every route every day and propose a schedule that optimizes the resources.
- also to make the system flexible, where I should be able to add the new bus-stops in between any two existing bus-stops, if required.

I know that graph databases gives me this flexibility. I will create graphs for each route, but where and how to store the data generated by those buses every 2-minutes!

To explain it clearly, I'm stuck in understanding how to model and store time stamps in a graph database. That is, I have to track the bus and store the location of the bus (bus-stop-id), time stamp at that bus-stop, and Geo-code.

How can I achieve this with graph-databases. Because every day, 20 buses in different routes generates lots of data.  How should I track and record all the data of 20 buses in a Neo4j like graphical databases.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The question is not that clear. What is your exact problem? You track buses and want to store the trajectory somewhere? Or do you want to "road match" the trajectories to an existing road network? Then have a look into routing engines e.g. based on OSM like GraphHopper and its map matching component (note: I'm the author)

Comment: Hello Karussell, i want to track the buses and store the trajectory. Each bus will go many rounds (to and fro) between source and destinaton. I want to track the buses and their complete traversing story. My concern is, if there is a 'to' edge between two stops , since bus comes many times to the stop, how to store a list of informaiton on the edge? how to store such huge amount of data, each edge in a day will have around 2 gb data, in  a month it will be too much. so how to kep such huge data on edge? right now iam doing analysis and got 8gb data, how to represnet on edges for analysis

Comment: I doubt it will be 2gb per edge but anyway: try to store your data more compact and use (de)serialization. For the graph itself there are more compact representations for special purpose graphs like road networks e.g. with graphhopper (note: I'm the author)